# How to send packets continuously through TCP?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, server

I have one server and multiple clients. The server is sending byte arrays(which includes some kind of messages inside) to the client and client parses those arrays into understandable forms.

Another point is, there is one special kind of message that the server send which client has to respond to it.

I want the server send regular messages continuously without expecting a response, and also special kind of message which expects a response and if it doesn't get it, it will terminate the connection.

How could I do that? I have been checking the net but could not find anything.

```
Server--->Client(Door Opened)
Server--->Client(Door Closed)
Server--->Client(Are You There?)
Client--->Server(Yeap)
Server--->Client(Plane Has Landed.)
Server--->Client(Are you There?)
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad, so the answer is broad, too.

Remember about *segregation of concerns* respectively *single responsibility principle*. Coming from there: you are actually looking at two **different** functionalities here:

- the regular data transfer from the server to known, connected clients (where no response is expected)
- some form of "hearbeat detection" - where the server asks the client to check if they are still reachable/alive

When you think about that, it becomes clear that you probably want to use completely different "components" within client and server to provide these two different functionalities. Like in: even having two **different** ports (and even different threads) within client/server.

So the server keeps a list of known clients. One thread is sending data to the clients; another thread is periodically iterating that list and asking for heart beat answers. If no answer is coming in time, that client gets removed from the list.

Comment: Yes, yet I was not able to find any kind of example on the net about those. Would it not be possible sending messages to client from server and it detects the ones that it has to respond? In anyway I think I need to know how to send packages contuniously, would you assist me with that?

Comment: As said: your question is going into the "too broad" direction. So, please first  read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question ... and think about that. And then come back with questions we could help with.